# How to sort array by first item in subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array with subarrays and wish to sort numerically and descending by the first item in the subarrays.  So for example, I wish to take the following array"

```
array = [[2,text],[5,text],[1,text]]
```

and sort it to become

```
array = [[5,text],[2,text],[1,text]]
```

Is there any simple function to use?  Thanks!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
array = [[2,text],[5,text],[1,text]];
array.sort(function(a,b){return a[0] < b[0]})
```

Comment: i'm glad that i could help sir,

Comment: Can this be set up generically, so that I can pass it which element to sort on?

Comment: @jlbriggs you can use closures for this like for example `function genericSort(index, arr) {array.sort(function(a,b){return a[index] < b[index]})}` and then you can call it as `array = [[2,3],[5,1],[1,2]];genericSort(0, array); /*this will sort on the first index*/ genericSort(1, array); and this one on the second` hope this could help

Comment: doesn't work. The right answer is below, with a "-" instead of a "<" !

Comment: @xem depends on browser. FF accepts true/false and +/-. Spyware (Chrome and its derivatives), and Safari/Webkit, only accept +/-

Answer (score 15):

```
array = [[2,text],[5,text],[1,text]];
array.sort(function(a,b){return a[0] - b[0]})
```

**working of the sort function**
if the function returns

- less than zero, sort a before b
- greater than zero, sort b before a
- zero, leave a and b unchanged with respect to each other

Additional information at [source](https://www.sitepoint.com/sophisticated-sorting-in-javascript/).

Comment: You can shorten that to `array.sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0])`

Answer (score 0):

```
array.sort(key=lambda x: x[0], reverse=True)
```